# Run blocking task in coroutine

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, python-asyncio, amazon-sqs

I have a server which reads messages from SQS queue with long polling which blocks coroutine execution. Is there a way to leave processors running while the scheduler is blocked on waiting for new messages?

```
import asyncio
import time

NUM_EXEC = 10

async def processor(i):
    print (f"Starting {i}")
    for n in range(10):
        print(f"Processor {i} cycle {n}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def scheduler():
    for i in range(NUM_EXEC):
        #Blocking SQS long poll
        time.sleep(5)
        #Run processor
        await asyncio.ensure_future(processor(i))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(scheduler())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To integrate with SQS, it is preferrable to use `aiobotocore` library - asyncio-compatible AWS driver. Here is example of SQS usage: http://aiobotocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#sqs

In general, if you must use an external library with blocking function calls - use [asyncio executors API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executor), which delegates blocking calls to thread pool.